# FileNotFoundError on jupyter notebook (at IBM Watson studio)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, opencsv

By running this script, I'm getting the "FileNotFoundError" message and I can't find a way to fix it. I changed the file and also name, but I still get this error.

```
#STEP 2.1 - Take the Latitude and Longitude from the CSV file
ll = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tayze\Geospatial.csv')
ll.sort_values(by='Postal Code', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

The error message is:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-bb01332243b3> in <module>
      3 """
      4 #STEP 2.1 - Take the Latitude and Longitude from the CSV file
----> 5 ll = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tayze\Geospatial.csv')
      6 ll.sort_values(by='Postal Code', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
      7 #print(ll.head())
```

Comment: Copy that file path, open notepad, then File --> Open... and paste the path. If you get the same error the file is not there. Are you running jupyter on your machine or on a server/cloud service?

Comment: Hey aneroid, I'm running using a server/cloud service (IBM Watson studio). Cause when I use the Spyder on my machine, I can read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment and your answer, you're running the notebook on a remote server. Ordinarily, **a remote machine cannot access your local drive.** If they could, it would be a serious security issue.

To work with local data, you need to upload it someplace where the cloud service can access it. From the [IBM Watson studio docs on accessing local data](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHGWL_1.2.3/local/datafiles.html):

> To upload the local data asset:
>
> 1. In your project, go to your Assets page and clickadd data set . Alternatively, you can click Add data set from the project pull-down menu.
> 2. Click the Local File tab.
> 3. Drag or browse to your local file system to the palette. The file is now added to the project.